# Is there a fix or workaround for the this platformResourceLoader error

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to make use of a 3rd javascript library in my LWC. The LWC is on a record page and shows this error when trying to load the page

[image]

If I add the component to an app page, it loads without a problem. The component class looks like this

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import chartsJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/charts';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class Illustration extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        loadScript(this, chartsJS);
    }
}
```

Using the debugger I can see the error is coming from the platformResourceLoader because the ownerDocument is undefined

```
function getDocument(cmp) {
  // Detect LWC type via duck-typing.
  if (cmp && cmp.template && cmp.template.host && cmp.template.host.ownerDocument) {
    const doc = cmp.template.host.ownerDocument;
    return doc;
  }

  throw new TypeError('The first parameter of loadScript() and loadStyle() must be an LWC component.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is strange that the lexical scope is not established already during this hook (and is also working on other apps / pages) you could try to move the the script loading to the renderedCallback method (with helper prop to avoid redundant loads) like in the d3 example of the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library)

Comment: I have just tried using the renderedCallback function with code similar to the link you provided but it still produces the same error

Comment: guess you have to get in touch with salesforce support then - don`t think anybody else can help you because even your first example should work and it is strange that based on the context it also does :(