# Unable to load styles and script from static resource in LWC after summer'19 release

Tags: lightning-web-components

one of my LWC component failed to work after the summer'19 release because it is unable to load styles not the script from the static resource

I have included the custom lwc inside a lightning record page

Here is the error which I am facing[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please [edit] your question to include your code that produces this error.  See [ask] for general expectations for questions. As we are a community, not a support channel, it's preferred that you not include "urgent" or "asap" requests.

Comment: I'm using loadScript and it's working fine in Summer '19. As requested, you should share some code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Looks like this issue is affected few orgs, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266346/is-there-a-fix-or-workaround-for-the-this-platformresourceloader-error 

Have you raised a case with SF

Comment: I have not raised a case with SF yet, that's why I have posted here to ensure if the error occurs for everyone after summer'19. Because the code was working perfectly fine before the summer'19 release. @PranayJaiswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce has listed this as a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SHoDQAW) on their support site, they also have provided a workaround for it.

The current workaround is to create another wrapper lwc custom component and use the custom component with platformResourceLoader in the wrapper.

**e.g --- c-lwc-wrapper --**

```
<template> 

<c-lwc-loader></c-lwc-loader> 

</template
```

where c-lwc-loader uses

```
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
```