# LWC is not loading after chaning the previous labels in static resource

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, salesforcedx-cli, salesforce-id, static-resources

i have the static resource in the salesforce it has few files related to the d3.js[i changed the label names in the d3v4,js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fOiJ.png)
after that i saved the modified d3v4.js file in the static resource,I not getting the lWC it is showing like this[image]

Comment: As Ankur said, we need to see how you're loading the script, if you're getting any errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have updated the reference in the LWC as well for fetching static resource, otherwise press F12 (Chrome Developer Tools) and check for any errors in the console tab.

Comment: Thank you for your response in the console log it shows failed to retrieve the d3v4.js from static resource

Comment: Can you please add some LWC code, how you are referencing static resource in your code?

Comment: or you can refer this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303155/lwc-unable-to-load-static-resource) for better understanding on how to load a static resource.

Comment: import D3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/AdvanceTraceability_StaticResource'; this is the line i am loading resource,previously it worked properly i am changed the label names in the d3v4.js now it is not working